# undefined reference glBindVertexArrayOES in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, opengl-es-2.0

All `GLES2` i use compile but these errors wont go away

> undefined reference to glBindVertexArrayOES
>
> undefined reference to glBindVertexArrayOES
>
> undefined reference to glGenVertexArraysOES
>
> undefined reference to glBindVertexArrayOES
>
> undefined reference to glBindVertexArrayOES

It seems as-if eclipse cannot find where these functions where defined which i dont understand since all other function are found perfectly, do i need to declare anything to make these work?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to call this from native code (using JNI)? Android doesn't provide access to all OpenGL ES functions from Java. I use GLES20Fix ([more info](http://dundercover.blogspot.com/2012/07/gles20fix.html)) in order to get access to missing OpenGL ES API. You can extend this JNI library with calls to GL ES API functions you need.

I've checked Android documentation and Java bindings doesn't have `glBindVertexArrayOES` function so it seems that you have to use JNI.

Comment: thanks for the answer, ive reverted back to GLES1 as i might not need GLES2 at all